# Regular Expression to select text between curly braces, Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm working on a way to filter and replace broken curly brace tags such as `{{hello}`. I've tried out a few regular expressions from here in Stack and tried on my own. The closes I've come is using this regex 
`(?=(\}(?!\})))((?<!\})\})` which selects the last tag in the example code block below. However it does not select the entire tag, it just selects the ending curly brace `}`.

```
{{hello}}
{{world}}}
{{foobar}}
{{hello}
```

What I need to do is select any tag that is missing the second ending curly brace like `{{hello}`. Can anyone help me with the regex to select this type of tag?

Comment: Maybe something like [`(?<!{){{[^{}]+}(?!})`](https://regex101.com/r/lG6wX5/1) will help.

Comment: Look at [`input.gsub(/(?<!{){{[^{}]+}(?!})/, "\\0}")`](http://ideone.com/Z4nxea). Or do you just want to get the "hello" string from the last "tag"?

Comment: Do you allow `{{test\}}}` and `{{this {{too}}}}`?

Comment: `I'm working on a way to filter and replace broken curly brace tags such as ` That's the problem, no machine can fix this once it's detected. It's a human thing. Otherwise code would write itself. You can only identify unbalanced syntax. Unless Ruby supports counting or recursion I'm pretty sure it can't be identified. If it does support recursion, you can only identify the unbalanced character (start or end) but nothing as far as content.

Comment: Thank you for all your input guys, @tadman, I just looking for `{{test}` our reads this as a broken tag, everything else is accepted or renders as plain text.

Comment: @Wiktor, thanks, your suggestions are great! I'll give them a shot.

Comment: Cary posted a similar solution. My regex just makes sure the first `{{` are not preceded with another `{` and the closing`}` is just not followed with `}`.

Comment: @wiktor, Thanks a lot! After doing some testing, your solution works best in our application. Its pretty much what we are looking to filter out. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I posted as an answer with explanations.

Answer (score 1):

> filter and replace broken curly brace tags

This problem is really easy to solve if you're not nesting things.

Try this:

```
[\{]+([^}]+)[}]+
```

Essentially, you can just replace the match with `{{\1}}` (or `{{$1}}`, I forget which one Ruby uses.)

It will work as long as there are one or more of `{` and `}` consecutively around the match.

Comment: Hi Laurel, Thank your for posting an answer. Your solution works in my application as well.

Answer (score 1):

I assume we are given a string containing substrings beginning with "{{",  followed by a "tag", which is a string of characters other than "{" and "}", followed by either "}" or "}}". We wish to return the tags that are followed by only one right brace. For example:

```
str = "Sue said {{hello}}, Bob said {{world}\nTom said {{foobar}}, Lola said {{hello}"
```

We can use the following regex:

```
r = /
    \{\{        # match {{
    ([^}]+)     # match one or more characters other than } in capture group 1
    \}          # match }
    (?:\z|[^}]) # match end of line or a character other than }
                # in a non-capture group        
    /x          # free-spacing regex definition mode

str.scan(r).flatten
  #=> ["world", "hello"]
```

The regex could of course be written in the conventional way:

```
r = /\{\{([^}]+)\}(?:\z|[^}])/
```

Note

```
str.scan(r)
  => [["world"], ["hello"]]
```

hence the need for `flatten`.

See [String#scan](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-scan) for an explanation.

Obviously, the same regex works if

```
str = "{{hello}}\n{{world}\n{{foobar}}\n{{hello}"

str.scan(r).flatten
  #> ["world", "hello"]
```

If

```
words = %w| {{hello}} {{world} {{foobar}} {{hello} |
  #=> ["{{hello}}", "{{world}", "{{foobar}}", "{{hello}"]
```

then

```
words.select { |w| w =~ r }.map { |w| w[/[^{}]+/] } 
  => ["world", "hello"]
```

Comment: Hi Cary, thank you for your solution and eloquent explanation, it works great. Wiktor's solution works great as well. Thank you for posting. I will come back and upvote you when I get enough reputation.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using the following expression:

```
/(?<!{){{[^{}]+}(?!})/
```

See the [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/vS8iJ9/2)

The pattern will match any string of text that **starts with `{{` *not preceded with `{`*, followed with any 1+ characters other than `{` and `}` and then a `}` that is *not followed with `}`***. Thus, this pattern matches strings of *exactly `{{xxx}` structure*.

Here is a [Ruby demo](http://ideone.com/Z4nxea):

```
"{{hello}".gsub(/(?<!{){{[^{}]+}(?!})/, "\\0}")
# => {{hello}}
```

**Pattern details**:

- `(?<!{)` - a negative lookbehind failing the match if a `{` appears immediately to the left of the current position
- `{{` - literal `{{`
- `[^{}]+` - 1+ characters other than `{` and `}` (to allow empty values, use `*` instead of `+`)
- `}` - a closing single `}`
- `(?!})` - a negative lookahead failing the match if a `}` appears right after the previously matched `}`.